# How do I make an if that says if variable.x has been < 0.1 for x amount of seconds then do something?

Tags: c++, directx

Tried looking this up but its a difficult worded question to search for.

So if say a ball is in the y position of 1 or less for at least 3 seconds then do something. I assume a timer but not sure how to set it up.
Ta.

Comment: What you want in your variable is about a thousand times more complex than a floating point variable.  So the answer to this question is create an entire event/trigger based framework or find one, then this is easy.  To do that step, I dunno, read a book on game programming, some books on graphics, play with a dozen tutorials, and make a decision informed by that experience?

Comment: You probably want multithreaded solution of something like this: https://ideone.com/nyByDn

Comment: Thanks for the link I'll give it a read. I love the downvotes despite noone being able to really answer the question lol. A slightly better wording would be "I have a variable that if it is under a value for longer than 3 seconds then do something"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this requires is a custom type for `x`. A industry-grade solution would use a template instead of hardcoding double, but I'm keeping it simple here.

Your class would look something like this :

```
class timedVariable {
   double value; // <double> would be replaced by template parameter
   std::chrono::steady_clock::timepoint lastChange;
public:
  timedVariable(double v) 
    : value(v)
    , lastChange(std::chrono::steady_clock::now())
  { }
  timedVariable(timedVariable const&) = default;
  timedVariable& operator=(timedVariable const&) = default;

  bool equalSince(double v, std::chrono::steady_clock::timepoint t)
  {
     // Ignoring the problem of double equality 
     return this->value == v && lastChange < t;
  }
};
```

The slight problem with "less than X for Y seconds" is that you need a fairly complete history of previous values. For instance, if you had values `0.1, 0.3, 0.2` in the past at timepoints 0, 1 and 2, and you check at moment 3, then it has been <=0.3 forever, but <=0.2 for one second. And you need the inverse history for "greater than X for Y seconds".

This is less of a problem if you can cap the history length up front. You may know that you only need 3 seconds of history at most, which means that when assigning a new value you can start out by discarding outdated history.